# What is the best approach to minifying CSS and JS files in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, drupal, drupal-7

I'm currently in the process of improving the performance of a Drupal site that I'm working on. I am currently using the Grunt task runner to concatenate and minify my JS and CSS, and I'm wanting to do the same for the core Drupal files.

I have currently aggregated the CSS and JS in the CMS (***configuration > development > performance***), I was wondering whether there are any reliable modules / settings that can enhance this functionality further?

Answer (score 1):

Minify is designed to improve the website performance.

This module provides the mechanism to render the page using minified version of HTML and JavaScript files.
Minified HTML is generated using regular expression, and JavaScript files are generated using GOOGLE Closure Compiler webservice. Minify also works perfectly with Boost module.

https://www.drupal.org/project/minify

Comment: Thanks for you input Rajveer gangwar, have you used this module yourself? Do you know if this minifies the core Drupal CSS and JS?